# how to redirect any url format to my domain?

Tags: redirect

I have a parkeddomain.com

It used to be a web application but I want any parkeddomain.com url to redirect to another domain

so

```
parkeddomain.com/signup would lead to anotherdomain.com
parkeddomain.com/page.php?q= would lead to anotherdomain.com
```

Comment: Probably better on webmasters than stackoverflow : http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=redirect+domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://anotherdomain.com
```