# Redirect all existing url to new url with different domain name

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I want to rewrite `wwww.mydomain.com` to `www.mynewdomain.com` in such a way that all old links pointing to `www.mydomain.com` would also work with `www.mynewdomain.com`.

For instance `www.mydomain.com/help` should be written to `www.mynewdomain.com`

Can anyone tell me the appropriate htaccess regex

Comment: What have __you__ tried so far?

Comment: I'm using php. I tried doing RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mynewdomian.com/$1 [R=301,L]
 but that doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to redirect any url format to my domain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903308/how-to-redirect-any-url-format-to-my-domain)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in DocumentRoot/.htaccess of old domain:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mynewdomian.com/? [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Won't this rewrite 'www.mydomain.com/help' to 'http://mynewdomain.com/help'? I think you should remove the `%{REQUEST_URI}' and add a 'www.' to produce that was asked.